# Show characters and variable values in subtitle

Tags: r, plot

I tried almost all combinations of paste(), bquote(), as.expression(), c(),...

```
plot(d[,"y"], type="l",xlim=c(1,n), ylim=c(min(d[,"y"]),max(d[,"y"])), 
  ylab="Y", xlab="T", main="ARMA(1,1)",
   sub=c(as.expression(bquote(phi == .(coef_ar)), 
         as.expression(bquote(theta == .(coef_ma))))))
```

This just plots "phi = 0.5" (the greek symbol in this case) but not the second part (the theta).
Can anyone help me please!

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `substitute`. `~` will concatenate together the expressions with a space

```
plot(1, main = substitute(phi == Phi ~ theta == Theta, list(Phi = 1, Theta = 1)))
```

[image]

or you can use `bquote` in a similar manner

```
plot(1, main = bquote(phi == .(coef_ar)  ~ theta == .(coef_ma)))
```

The reason your initial approach did not work is because it creates a vector of expressions, and then used only the first element for the subtitle.

If you want `comma` separated values, then use `list()`,

eg

```
 plot(1, main = bquote(list(phi == .(coef_ar), theta == .(coef_ma))))
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you. Yes, i thought that too. That was my last approach. The built-in reference was a little foggy about that to me. Or I am too tired :P

Comment: `?plotmath` is full of useful information, but perhaps shouldn't be tackled in a foggy state.